# Stop embeded video from autoplaying

Tags: flash, video

Hi I've literally tried everything and cant get anything to work. I'm trying to get a video to **not** autoplay.

I have added what code i have to [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKZ8Z/)

Can anyone help please!

Thanks Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you loading the video? Do you use FLVPlayback?
There is a checkbox in the FLVPlayback component parameters called autoplay.

I can't really see how your Flash File is constructed on the fiddle site.

If you didn't create the Flash you shoudl try to obtain the FLV video.

If that is not an option you could load the swf into a new swf, then try to find the FLVPlayback, or whatever is playing and stop it. But you will need a crossdomain on their server or a local copy of the swf.

Sample code of loading an swf, finding the autoplaying FLVPLayback and stopping it:

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.video.*;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_Complete);
loader.load(new URLRequest("PATH-TO-VIDEO.swf"));

function loader_Complete(e:Event)
{
    addChild(loader.content);

    //here i get the videoplayer and stop it
    var targetPlayer:FLVPlayback = MovieClip(loader.content).getChildAt(0) as FLVPlayback;
    targetPlayer.stop();
}
```